# Hide details of ParametricFunction

Tags: output-formatting, parametric-functions

I use `ParametricNDSolve` to return a particular combination of the (vector) variables, at the end of the integration range.

This gives a `ParametricFunction` with the gory details in the output box, that I would like to hide if possible:

[image]

A smaller definite example:

```
f = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Y'[x] == q Y[x], Y[0] == Table[1, 4], 
  v'[x] == Sin[x], v[0] == 0}, 
 Exp[-v[4]]*Sin[v[4] + 1] Y[4].Y[4], {x, 0, 4}, q];
```

Then if I ask for `f`, I get the full description:

```
f
```

[image]

Is there a neat way to do this, that will not slow down the evaluation at parameter values?

Comment: What about `;` after `ParametricNDSolveValue[[...]`?

Comment: The function is the output of one function, to then be used later on in my package for finding roots, plotting etc. I know this is a small thing, but people are likely to just use the first function without a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function as the second argument:

```
func[a_, b_] := Exp[-a] Sin[a+1] b.b
g = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {Y'[x]==q Y[x], Y[0]==Table[1,4], v'[x]==Sin[x], v[0]==0},
    Unevaluated @ func[v[4],Y[4]],
    {x, 0, 4},
    q
]
```

> [image]

It still works:

```
f /@ Range[0, 4]
g /@ Range[0, 4]
```

> {0.358834, 1069.67, 3.18864*10^6, 9.5052*10^9, 2.83346*10^13}
>
> {0.358834, 1069.67, 3.18864*10^6, 9.5052*10^9, 2.83346*10^13}

Comment: Thank you. I tried something similar with `Hold` but that didn't work.